# How to change alternate items color in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, colors, background-color, react-native-flatlist

I am using a FlatList which has 2 columns in one row. I want to add background colour in such a way so that 2 items in one row and same column does not have same colour.I want different colour for opposite items.

If you check this image this has two colours one is black and another is white sop I want if the 1st item is white and second is black then 3rd cannot be white as same column and adjacent row don't have same colour. I want opposite items have different colours. Please help and check this image for more information here...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68hzk.png)

Answer (score 0):

just use a switch case statement

```
switch(index%3){
    case 0 : 
        background = "white"
        break;
    case 1 : 
        background = "black"
        break;
    case 2 : 
        background = "grey"
        break;
}
```

Comment: thankyou but it will not work like for 8th index remainder is 2, for 7th is 1 because remainder can be 0,1,2

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by that